# Django Restframework N to N Table

Tags: python, django, rest

I have two classes in my model.py:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    process = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

For these two classes I created a serializer each:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Table.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name) 
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

(same for Activity)

I now want to store the relation between table and activity. An activity can have multiple tables. Now I don't know if I need to create a new class like this:

```
class TableActivity(models.Model):
    activtiy = models.ManyToManyField('Activity')
    table = models.ManyToManyField('Table')
```

Or that this can be included into the activity already?
How should my model/serializer look like then?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create class TableActivity. You can add field `activtiy = models.ManyToManyField('Activity')` to table `Table` or add field `table = models.ManyToManyField('Table')` to table `Activity`. And you should use [model serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) for creating object in database

Comment: So adding the table field to activity makes sense, but the list of tables should already be predefined and when you create a new activity you need to select from the list of tables (or create a new one). Would it still be the same?